# Defining a recursive method that takes several arguments

Tags: ruby, recursion

What do I define a recursive method with variable arguments in ruby?

I was thinking

```
    def meth(var, *var)     
      meth(var,var)
    end
```

If I do it like that, var becomes an array in the next iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the splat when you call it as well (like you would with & when passing a block rather than defining one):

```
def meth(var, *var)     
  meth(var,*var)
end
```

Least surprise!